# Is it possible to redirect TCP connections

Tags: networking, tcp, firewall

Given the following scenario:

- Computer A connects to a public server from behind a firewall.
- Computer B connects to the same public server from behind a firewall.

Now, is there any way for Computer A to talk directly to Computer B using those outbound connections without sending all data through the server?

Can the server link those connections somehow?

Two peers, talking to each other, using outbound connections instead of dealing with inbound firewall issues.

Comment: Punch "NAT [hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching)" into your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, yes.  Easy, no.

At least one of the firewalls needs to be updated to forward a port on the external IP to a port on the machine behind it.  The other machine can then connect to that port to open a bidirectional TCP/IP connection.

To accomplish this, you can make use of [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) on the firewall to accomplish "hole punching" or "[NAT traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#NAT_traversal)".

Once the firewall port is open, you forward that port number over the public server and pass it along with the public IP address already known to the server along to the other machine.  It can now create the connection.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that it can be achieved mate. Unless you have access to the public server network and create a route to direct incoming A directly to the B and vice versa.